# react-native-sound audio don't reproduce

Tags: javascript, audio, react-native

I want to play audio in fetch function every time, when array length changes:

```js
 componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      // Loads sound
      this.doneSound = new Sound('done.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE);

      // Fetch data
      this.fetch();
      this.fetchInterval = setInterval(() => { this.fetch(); }, 1000);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

fetch = () => {
  fetch('this.url')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.fetching = false;

        let list1 = [];

        if (responseJson.list.length > 0) {
          list1 = responseJson.list.filter(item => item.status === 1);
        }
       
        // playng sound every time array length changing
        if (this.difference(list1, this.state.list1).length > 0) {
          this.notification_sound();
        }

        this.setState({list1: list1});
      })
  }

difference = (list1, list2) => {
    list2 = list2.map(item => item.id);
    return list1.filter(item => (list2.indexOf(item.id) === -1) ? item.id : false);
  }
```

Fetch function is called every second. In simulator it plays every time, but on real device it plays only first time. Android app. I'm using [zmxv/react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound). Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: https://react-native-track-player.js.org/install/
I heavily suggest ditch rn sound and use this lib.

Comment: Isn't it overkill for just one sound to play?

Comment: I think it's more lightweight than sound. also, you can add or remove from the array like a player you can write custom functionality for it. the RN sound is not that flexible.

Comment: ok, i will try. Thank you!